# How to move to the other side of the trunk a full branch of a tree made with TikZ?

Tags: tikz-trees

I am a beginner in LaTeX, and trying to make my first tree diagram with TikZ. I have borrowed one sample of code and adapted it. I would like however to move the branch "Automatic formatting" to the left side of the trunk, in order to reduce the height of the diagram, but could not figure how to adapt the parameters. Can someone suggest a solution, and possibly any other change that would improve the look (or clarity and impact..?) of the diagram?

```
\documentclass[11pt ]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{trees}

\begin{document}
\tikzstyle{every node}=[draw=black,thick,anchor=west, fill=red!20, text width=14em, text centered,  minimum height=1.5em, inner sep=0pt, auto, rounded corners= .1 ex]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  grow via three points={one child at (0.5,-0.7) and
  two children at (0.5,-0.7) and (0.5,-1.4)},
  edge from parent path={(\tikzparentnode.south) |- (\tikzchildnode.west)}]
  \node {Productivity}
child { node [fill=blue!20] {Full structuration}}
child { node  [fill=orange!20]{Automatic formatting}
child { node  [fill=orange!20]{Creation of tables and plots}}
child { node  [fill=orange!20]{Easy integration of pictures}}
child { node  [fill=orange!20]{Auto/easy native graphics}}
child { node [fill=orange!20]{Auto/easy changes}}
child { node  [fill=orange!20]{Sharing of libraries}}
child { node  [fill=orange!20]{Easy splitting of draft file}}
} %
child [missing] {}
child [missing] {}
child [missing] {}
child [missing] {}
child [missing] {}
child [missing] {}
child { node  [fill=green!20]{Simultaneous editing}}
child { node  [fill=green!20]{Short learning curve}}
child { node  [fill=green!20]{Training material}}
child { node  [fill=gray!20]{Stability of software}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several ways to move a node and its children to the left side. One possibility is to adapt the node properties, e.g. like this:

```
\documentclass[11pt ]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{trees}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
\tikzstyle{every node}=[draw=black,thick,anchor=west, fill=red!20, text width=14em, text centered,  minimum height=1.5em, inner sep=0pt, auto, rounded corners= .1 ex]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  grow via three points={one child at (0.5,-0.7) and
  two children at (0.5,-0.7) and (0.5,-1.4)},
  edge from parent path={(\tikzparentnode.south) |- (\tikzchildnode.west)}]
  \node {Productivity}
child { node (A) [fill=blue!20] {Full structuration}}
child { node  [fill=green!20]{Simultaneous editing}}
child { node  [fill=green!20]{Short learning curve}}
child { node  [fill=green!20]{Training material}}
child { node  [fill=gray!20]{Stability of software}}
child[
   grow via three points={one child at (-0.5,-0.7) and
   two children at (-1.6,-0.7) and (-1.6,-1.4)},
   edge from parent path={(\tikzparentnode.south) |- (\tikzchildnode.east)}]
{ node  [left=of A,fill=orange!20]{Automatic formatting}
   child { node  [fill=orange!20,anchor=west]{Creation of tables and plots}}
   child { node  [fill=orange!20]{Easy integration of pictures}}
   child { node  [fill=orange!20]{Auto/easy native graphics}}
   child { node [fill=orange!20]{Auto/easy changes}}
   child { node  [fill=orange!20]{Sharing of libraries}}
   child { node  [fill=orange!20]{Easy splitting of draft file}}
};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The resulting tree looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Excellent. I had no idea about the "left=of A," possibility. I   have noticed the use of the library \usetikzlibrary{positioning}. Where is it possible to find documentation about the various  TikZ libraries?

Comment: My main source for TikZ/PGF is the [manual](http://mirror.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/generic/pgf/pgfmanual.pdf) coming with the package. It contains the documentation of all core libraries as well. Together with the wide range of different examples at [TeXample.net](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples) I'm usually able to get most of my PGF questions answered.